# 30 FPS with 60Hz monitor?

Tags: monitor

Starting today I started playing Team Fortress 2 again, and it was locked at 30 fps since I had G-Sync on. Then I went on Minecraft, and I still had 30 fps because it was still on. The thing is, my monitor's refresh rate is 60Hz, and I've made sure that it was still on 60Hz so I have no idea what's going on. Any help?

Comment: Refresh rate is the maximum times per second your monitor can refresh the screen. It has nothing to do with how many frames per second a game can deliver content. (Refresh rate limits it, but they are not necessarily related.)  Point is, there must be something else limiting it, most likely a setting in your graphics driver.

Comment: Yeah, my refresh rate is 60Hz. For the past three years with VSync, 60Hz = 60 FPS. Now all of a sudden 60Hz = 30 FPS

Comment: As I said, there must be something else limiting your FPS. The two numbers (refresh rate and FPS) don't have to be equal. Perhaps check your game settings, or update your gfx driver?

Comment: What else would be limiting it? I just played Black Ops 2 and it's fine, no problem, but with Minecraft and TF2 it's at 30... I have no idea what happened within the last few hours.

Comment: Maybe this will help.. http://www.avadirect.com/blog/frame-rate-fps-vs-hz-refresh-rate/

Comment: I'm not asking how it works, I'm asking what's causing this all of a sudden and if there's someone either experiencing the same problem, or knows how to fix this.

Comment: Learning how it works may help you figure it out. Don't read it if you don't want to, just trying to help.

Comment: I read it all, and I do appreciate the help. I already knew somewhat how refresh rate and VSync have differences yet still correlate with one another, I just need a fix to this somewhat ignorant and annoying problem.

Comment: If a v-synced game delivers 30 FPS with 60Hz sync, it means the game is not able to render its frames in 16,6 milliseconds. It may be able to reach 40, 50 or 59 FPS unsyncronized, but because frames are syncronized, those that aren't ready are not drawn. This is the answer for your question. Now, if you had TF2 and Minecraft running on 60Hz before, and are wondering what happened now - please reword your question as such, and try to recall what has changed.

Comment: Also, problems can not be "ignorant" :-)

Comment: What hardware do you have? Laptop? What video card?

Comment: GTX 760 SC ACX on a desktop